# Проблема масштабируемости рисунка img в div контейнере

Tags: html, css

Есть рисунок который я поместил в контейнер. Контейнер имеет свойство `border: 5px ridge #254c72;`. Проблема в том, что когда я масштабирую страницу, между рисунком и рамкой контейнера появляется пространство свободное. Оно может возникнуть с любой стороны, либо с обеих одновременно. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему. `margin:0` и `padding:0` проблемы не решают.

```
 <style>
    content div{
        border: 5px ridge #254c72;
        display: inline-block;        
    }
    content img{
        display:block;
    }
 </style>
```

```
<header>
    <img src="img/title.jpg" alt="header image">
</hader>
<h1>Компьютерная графика и web-дизайн</h1>
<content>
    <div><img src="design/small/p0.jpg" alt="sunset"></div>
    <div><img src="design/small/p1.jpg" alt="girl"></div> 
    <div><img src="design/small/p2.jpg" alt="cats"></div>
    <div><img src="design/small/p3.jpg" alt="matrix"></div>
    <div><img src="design/small/p4.jpg" alt="abstraction"></div>
    <div><img src="design/small/p5.jpg" alt="step"></div>
    <div><img src="design/small/p6.jpg" alt="suslic and suslikcathead"></div>
</content>
```

[image: на этой картинки слева и справа появился отступ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос тем, что задал картинке свойство margin: -1px;. Результат меня устроил. Скорее всего это лишь некоректная работа Хрома, так как в Файерфоксе ничего похожего с бордерами не наблюдалось. Если бы свойство border находилось на картинке, проблема бы не исчезла.

Comment: Кстати, бывают еще проблемы из-за неадекватных округлений дробных пикселов. Поэтому часто лечит что-то вроде `margin:-0.5px`  и даже ... `-0`!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант простой: из тега img перенесите изображение в фон DIV'а. У вас во-первых будет меньше кода и во вторых - фон проще настроить, как по мне. DIV'у добавите размеры и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Плюс браузер будет фон более "настойчиво" кэшировать.

Comment: минус – если не знаешь размеров картинки, то вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Примените бордер не к контейнеру, я прямо к `img`.

Comment: Пробовал, к сожелению эффект тот же.

Comment: тогда попробуйте явно указать размеры контейнера, равные размерам картинки.